# Do dead party members gain experience in Baldur's Gate 3?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

In Baldur's Gate 3, if a member of my party dies during a fight, do they still gain experience when the fight is completed if I revive them later on?

Comment: I'm not certain, but given that idle party members in your camp get xp too, the same probably goes for dead ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, party members gain experience while dead.

I once finished a combat with one dead party member, the other party members gained a level from it, and the last one gained the level immediately after being resurrected.